# Включение подсветки ошибок в CodeRush

Tags: c#, devexpress

Подскажите, как включить подсветку ошибок в CodeRush для Visual Studio 2013 и существует ли вообще такая подсветка.
Вот, например, пишу

```
var _myVariable=new List<string>();
__myVariable.Count;
```

Хотелось бы чтобы __myVariable он подчеркнул или выделил цветом, что мол, нет такой переменной и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeRush не отключает стандартное поведение.

После установки CodeRush имеет две схемы настроек FrictionFree и Default, первая ставится по умолчанию и в ней включено минимальное количество визуальных фич, в том числе отключена подсветка незадекларированных элементов. Переключиться между схемами настроек можно на тулбаре:

[image: тулбар]

Либо изменить настройку подсветки незадекларированных элементов в опциях:

[image: Настройки]

Answer (score 0):

Обычная студия, без всяких аддонов, подчеркивает вторую строчку красным. И в тултипе пишет что нет такое переменной.

Скорее всего CodeRush просто ломает или отключает стандартное поведение студии. Поведение можно включить или выключить в настройках:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Underline Errors.